# How to setup Android artifacts using the JFrog Platform?

Tags: android, gradle, artifactory, bintray

I have been using the JFrog Bintray to upload/download Android libraries from the cloud.
Recently I have noticed JFrog Bintray is sunsetting:
https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/

So by May 1st 2021, I have to move to JFrog Platform. However, setting the environment is not straight forward.

What I need:

- Use the cloud server
- Use the Gradle so that the Android Studio can call the artifact library version to easily load my libraries

What I am confused:

- I am confused if I want the "cloud" option, then I need to create "local repository" or "remote repository". If remote repository, then is it OK to use the URL "https://jcenter.bintray.com"?
- Android example sample code of how to download from the Android Studio is missing
- Android example sample code of how to publish from the Android Studio is missing
- My original Bintray artifacts will stop working(not able to download from Android Studio) as of May 1st 2021?

It could be my lack of searching skills, but I cannot find any examples how to setup Android Studio to use JFrog Platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local/remote repositories aren't related to cloud v.s. on-prem.
You deploy artifacts to local repositories (and then you can download them).
You download artifacts from remote repositories, which proxy central artifacts servers such as bintray & maven-central.
You will still be able to use bintray for your remote repositories until February 1st 2022, see [blog](https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/) for details. Since you're working on a clean setup I recommend using maven-central.
You can find details of how to setup a remote gradle repository in the [official documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Working+with+Gradle), including a video at the bottom.